# How to populate my Django Model 'updated_by' field with logged in User automatically using a formset?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I am a beginner with Django and I have been enjoying it so far. I figured out how to use model formsets, but I cannot figure out how to make my form automatically use logged in User as the 'updated_by' field.

## models.py

```
class Inventory(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    stock = models.IntegerField()
    par = models.IntegerField()
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    phone = PhoneField(blank='True', help_text='Contact Phone Number')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self):
        super().save()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in your views.py. Try getting request.user before saving the form.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should have made form for Inventory if yes(let InvntoryForm) than in view.py file you have done something like this:-

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
      Inven_form=InventoryForm(data=request.POST)

       if Inven_form.is_valid():
           user=Inven_form.save()
           #in between add this
           Inven_form.updated_by=request.user.username
           user.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the 'commit=False' argument which will create a new object and assign it without saving to your database.  You can then set the user attribute and call save() with no arguments.

For example, this is how I assigned the user attribute to my blog app.

in views.py

```
if form.is_valid():
            # Create a new entry and assign to new_article.
            new_article = form.save(commit=False)

            # Set the new article attribute to the current user.
            new_article.user = request.user

            # Save to database now the object has all the required data.
            new_article.save()
```

Here is the full code for the add_article view if this helps.

```
@login_required
def add_article(request):
    """ Add a new article. """
    if request.method != 'POST':
        # No data submitted, create a blank form.
        form = AddArticleForm()
    else:
        # POST data submitted, process data.
        form = AddArticleForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_article = form.save(commit=False)
            new_article.author = request.user
            new_article.save()
            return back_to_blog_page()

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'add_article.html', context)
```